# Quering numbers containing hyphens with SOLR WordDelimiterFilterFactory isn't working?

Tags: search, solr

I'm trying to configure solr 4.0-BETA with a `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` so I can query numbers containing hyphens.

Field value: "123456-1234" when adding to `ssn`.

Queries:

"123456-1234" <- Works (with hyphen) 
"1234561234" <- Doesn't work  (without hyphen)

According to the documentation (AFAIUI) it should match since the fieldtype has `generateNumberParts` and `catenateNumbers`.

From the documentation:

> generateNumberParts="1" causes number subwords to be generated:
>   "500-42" => "500" "42" 
>   catenateNumbers="1" causes maximum runs of
>   number parts to be catenated: "500-42" => "50042"

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory

My fields:

```
<fields>
     <field name="ssn" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />
     <field name="ssn_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
</fields>

<copyField source="ssn" dest="ssn_exact" />
<copyField source="ssn" dest="text" />
```

The filter in `text_en_splitting`:

```
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Related: [Search with various combinations of space, hyphen, casing and punctuations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29783237/55075).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a similar field in my local schema and using the analysis tool which is under the Solr Admin. (`http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/analysis` - Note this url assumes solr running on `http://localhost:8983/` and your index is named `collection1` - modify as necessary).

I tried running your value to index and the query against text_en_splitting selected in the Analyse FieldName/FieldType dropdown. You will see from the results that the value 1234561234 is never added as an index term for this field type.

However, if you use the text_en_splitting_tight FieldType, then the behavior you want is being produced as the hypen is removed and 1234561234 is a term being added to the index. So I would  switch the field type as follows and reindex and you should be set to go.

```
<fields>
 <field name="ssn" type="text_en_splitting_tight" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />
 <field name="ssn_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
</fields>

<copyField source="ssn" dest="ssn_exact" />
<copyField source="ssn" dest="text" />
```